# Programmatically calling click event doesn't do what really clicking event does

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

I am using Angular to develop a client-server application, but this is not an Angular problem, or maybe it is.

On one page I have a button that opens a modal with 2 buttons. One is for submitting and the other one is for closing. They both work if they are actually clicked.

The problem is that I want the Submit button to close the modal, i.e. do what the close button does.

I open the modal like this:

```
@ViewChild(AddAfmStatementIdentifiersComponent) createAfmStatementIdentifiers: any = {};
    CreateAfmStatementIdentifiers() {

        this.createAfmStatementIdentifiers.afmStatementIdentifiers = this.afmStatementIdentifiers;
        this.createAfmStatementIdentifiers.open();

    }
```

the 2 buttons are:

```
<div id="responsive-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1"  role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modifica avizul</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <form novalidate class="form-horizontal p-t-20">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                <div class="form-group has-success">
                                    <h4 class="entity-info"><label for="denumire" class="label-has-danger"> Serie </label></h4>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="input-group-addon"><img src="/images/Deseuri/serieDocument.svg" alt="document series" class="img-responsive" /></div>
                                        <input type="text" id="serie" name="serie" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="afmStatementIdentifiers.barcodeIdentifier" data-validation-required-message="campul nu poate fi gol!">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" *ngIf="barcodeIdentifierErrors.length > 0">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li *ngFor="let error of barcodeIdentifierErrors">
                                            {{ error }}
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                <div class="form-group has-success">
                                    <h4 class="entity-info"><label for="denumire" class="label-has-danger"> Numar inceput </label></h4>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="input-group-addon"><img src="/images/Deseuri/numarDocument.svg" alt="document start number" class="img-responsive" /></div>
                                        <input type="text" id="startNumber" name="startNumber" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="afmStatementIdentifiers.version" data-validation-required-message="campul nu poate fi gol!">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" *ngIf="versionErrors.length > 0">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li *ngFor="let error of versionErrors">
                                            {{ error }}
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-red animated flipInX flipInY lightSpeedIn slideInUp" data-dismiss="modal" id="closeButton">
                    <i class="fa fa-window-close"></i> Close
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-add animated flipInX flipInY lightSpeedIn slideInUp" (click)="submit()">
                    <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Save
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in the parent I call this method in the child:

```
cancel() {
    $('#closeButton').click()
    this.isOpen = false;
}
```

All works, but these 2 divs:

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
<div class="sweet-overlay" tabindex="-1" style="opacity: -0.04; display: none;"></div>
```

remain in the html and they make all the interface unclickable

The user needs to refresh the page to be able to click on any other button.

But actually clicking on the "Close" button removes those divs.

How can I dispose of the modal correctly when clicking on the submit button?

Comment: Sounds like `<div id="responsive-modal" class="modal fade"` does not get the click too

Comment: why are you using jquery with angular2? and why dont you use normal click events instead of event listeners?

Comment: because I am a begginer. This is how I know to do it for now :(